# Texture Painting - make it look more 3D / realistic and change it's settings

Tags: mesh, texturing, texture-painting

I've made a ceramic plate and wanted to have "left over ketchup smears" on it. So i made the PBR for white ceramics then combined that with an image texture using a mix shader.

I then found an image of ketchup and painted on the ketchup. Still experimenting at this time but the main issue i have is that the ketchup itself looks too "painted on" and i'd quite like to bring it to life and sort of 3D.

[image]

I thought about using sculpt and inflate brush but that doesn't really look very good (at least the way i did it).
I tried to make a new mesh for the ketchup only which i could add onto the plate but then it's quite hard to get that accurate irregular shape.

I thought there should maybe be a way to create some geometry or bump based on how dark the red colour is?

Any ideas on how to change the settings of the texture paint to make it pop or indeed better ways of achiveing this look?

Many thanks

Comment: Feed the texture color into a Vector Bump or Vector Displace node? Maybe use a SeparateRGB node to get the red channel and/or a Converter Color Ramp to adjust the levels.